# How to disable short parameter names

Tags: powershell, parameters

Given:

```
function foo() {
    Param(
        [alias()]
        $title
    )
    $null -eq $title
    echo $title
}
```

Then calling it with both `-title` and `-t` results in an error:

```
PS> foo -title hi -t bar
foo : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'title' is specified more than
once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values,
use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".
At line:1 char:15
+ foo -title hi -t bar
+               ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [foo], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterAlreadyBound,foo
```

This happens also if I omit the alias directive. How can I fix this so that foo only recognizes `-title` as the `$title` parameter (withoug adding a `$t` parameter)?

Comment: Don't pass parameters twice? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: To answer your immediate question, PowerShell doesn't have "short parameters", so there's nothing to disable. PowerShell recognizes parameters by the shortest unique match, meaning `-title`, `-t`, or `-ti` are the same parameter. If you have 2 parameters like `-title` and `-tag` then the shortest unique match would be `-ti` and `-ta` respectively, and using `-t` would throw an ambiguous parameter error.

Comment: Even if I give the variable name $__title, it still accepts -t. 
And in my use case, 'foo' is a wrapper for another command that has these other parameters. It is just super weird I can't disable powershell's handling unique match.

Comment: Add the parameters from the other command to the wrapper: `Function Foo($t, $title) {Echo $title; OtherCommand -t:$t}`?

Comment: @IttayD If you need to pass a particular subset of arguments through to another command/function take a look at LotPing's answer and my comment to it.

Answer (score 3):

If (for whatever reason) you pass parameters not destined to the function,
which interfere with other named parameters you might insert the stop parsing parameter [--%](https://ss64.com/ps/stop-parsing.html) as a workaround:

```
function foo() {
    Param(
        [alias()] $title,
        [parameter(mandatory=$false, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]$Remaining
    )
    "title:    " + $title
    "remaining:" + $Remaining

    $PSBoundParameters
}
```

---

```
> foo -title bar --% -t (date)
title:    bar
remaining:--% -t (date)

Key       Value
---       -----
title     bar
Remaining {--%, -t (date)}
```

## EDIT an alternative, due to [AnsgarWiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705490/how-to-disable-short-parameter-names/57711228?noredirect=1#comment101866172_57711228) good hint:

```
> foo -title bar -- -t (date)
title:    bar
remaining:-t 08/29/2019 16:17:57

Key       Value
---       -----
title     bar
Remaining {-t, 2019-08-29 16:17:57}
```

Comment: Beware that a limitation of `--%` is that it completely stops evaluation of the arguments, meaning that you can't use variables in the remainder of the commandline. An undocumented (or at least to my knowledge not very well documented) feature is `--`, which does the same as in Linux shells: prevent the shell from parsing the rest of the commandline as parameters. `foo -title bar -- -t $baz` should produce "bar" as the title and "-t" and the value of `$baz` as the remainder.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the hint, incorporated it into my answer.

Comment: here is the offical doc link to the --% and -- token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#the-stop-parsing-token

Comment: Thanks for the link, @JasonSong. To mention the official names here: `--%` is the _stop-parsing token_, `--` is the _end-of-parameters token_.